# Can't run jest on travis since upgrading to babel 7

Tags: react-native, travis-ci, jestjs, babeljs

I am able to run my tests locally but on travis I get the following error:

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
      at ScriptTransformer._getTransformer (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:231:19)
```

I have a react-native project, I recently upgraded to Babel 7 and had alot of problems with jest. Consequently I had to add the following to my package.json.

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
},
```

my babel.rc file is as follows:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-gauge": "^0.1.10",
    "react-navigation": "~2.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.10.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^5.13.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.61.0",
    "jest": "^23.2.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native-webpack-server": "^0.9.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest/setup.js"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./jest/afterTestFramework",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|react-clone-referenced-element)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*(test|spec))\\.jsx?$"
  }
}
```